# ASP.NET Routing block asp.net menu control from showing horizntal sub menus

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-routing, aspmenu-control

I am working on a project which is complete & while testing & found that ASP.NET Routing blocks menu from showing up on pages with friendly URL (ASP.Net 4.0, C#)

Routing Code

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ActivityRoute", "en/activity/{Language}/{EventID}/{PageID}/{EventTitle}", "~/en/Activity-Details.aspx", false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
                { "Language", "en-US"},
                { "EventID", "0" },
                { "PageID", "0"},
                { "EventTitle", "event-not-found" }},
            new RouteValueDictionary {   
                {"Language", "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}"},
                { "EventID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                { "PageID", "[0-9]{1,8}" }
            });
```

Everything is working fine & managed to make Fancybox work with friendly URL but i am not able to figure out what is blocking sub menus from showing up on page with friendly URL.

I managed to resolve this issue as it was due to path

Comment: Resolved it was a general path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it, Problem was due to the path issue which was resolved